# Problem passing renderItem to FlatList as prop in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a reusable FlatList component, for this I need to pass renderItem function as a prop to my reusable component but for some reason the renderItem components are not showing up.

In my parent component:

```
const itemView = ({ item, index }) => 
    {
        return <ReviewCard3 item={item} />
    };

<RList1 onEndReachedAction={venueReviewStore.list} data={data} renderItem={itemView}></RList1>
```

In my children (reusable list component

```
const { ...rest } = props;

<FlatList  style={{ flex:1,backgroundColor:'rgb(235,235,235)'}}  data={data} keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()} extraData={loader}
        onEndReached={ ()=>{ onEndReached() } } onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        {...rest}
        />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give me a snack url?